# Blank Screen - Matter.js

Tags: javascript, html, matter.js

matter.js -

This is [one of the demo](https://brm.io/matter-js/demo/#slingshot) from matter.js. It returns a blank screen. I have tried several approaches and spent hours and hours on this, still can't figure out what is wrong here.

I've checked brackets, syntax and typo but it still returns a blank screen.

I've checked matter.js is loading correctly in the background.

Can someone kindly point out the mistakes here?

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

//Fetch our canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('world22');

    var Engine = Matter.Engine,
        Render = Matter.Render,
        Runner = Matter.Runner,
        Composites = Matter.Composites,
        Events = Matter.Events,
        Constraint = Matter.Constraint,
        MouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint,
        Mouse = Matter.Mouse,
        World = Matter.World,
        Bodies = Matter.Bodies;

    // create engine
    var engine = Engine.create(),
        world = engine.world;

    // create renderer
    var render = Render.create({
        // element: document.body,
        canvas: canvas,
        engine: engine,
        options: {
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            showAngleIndicator: true,
        }
    });

    Render.run(render);

    // create runner
    var runner = Runner.create();
    Runner.run(runner, engine);

    // add bodies
    var ground = Bodies.rectangle(395, 600, 815, 50, { isStatic: true }),
        rockOptions = { density: 0.004 },
        rock = Bodies.polygon(170, 450, 8, 20, rockOptions),
        anchor = { x: 170, y: 450 },
        elastic = Constraint.create({ 
            pointA: anchor, 
            bodyB: rock, 
            stiffness: 0.05
        });

    var pyramid = Composites.pyramid(500, 300, 9, 10, 0, 0, function(x, y) {
        return Bodies.rectangle(x, y, 25, 40);
    });

    var ground2 = Bodies.rectangle(610, 250, 200, 20, { isStatic: true });

    var pyramid2 = Composites.pyramid(550, 0, 5, 10, 0, 0, function(x, y) {
        return Bodies.rectangle(x, y, 25, 40);
    });

    World.add(engine.world, [ground, pyramid, ground2, pyramid2, rock, elastic]);

    Events.on(engine, 'afterUpdate', function() {
        if (mouseConstraint.mouse.button === -1 && (rock.position.x > 190 
 rock.position.y < 430)) {
            rock = Bodies.polygon(170, 450, 7, 20, rockOptions);
            World.add(engine.world, rock);
            elastic.bodyB = rock;
        }
    });

    // add mouse control
    var mouse = Mouse.create(render.canvas),
        mouseConstraint = MouseConstraint.create(engine, {
            mouse: mouse,
            constraint: {
                stiffness: 0.2,
                render: {
                    visible: false
                }
            }
        });

    World.add(world, mouseConstraint);

    // keep the mouse in sync with rendering
    render.mouse = mouse;

    // fit the render viewport to the scene
    Render.lookAt(render, {
        min: { x: 0, y: 0 },
        max: { x: 800, y: 600 }
    });


        });
  </script>

<canvas id="world22"></canvas>
```

Comment: Which errors show in the console (dev tools)?

Comment: @GetSet No error message is shown

Comment: Where is your `return` object at the end going? Looks like nowhere where it gets handled.

Comment: @GetSet Thanks. That session is redundant. I just copied and paste it from the demo script without cleaning up. I have updated the code without the `return`.

Comment: Alrighty then. Well possibly the way the demo was written, the code you removed served a purpose to get things jumpstarted. Which demo in particular are you referencing? Can you provide a link?

Comment: @GetSet Thanks. I might be wrong but I don't think that section serves a purpose. I reckon that was for running on the demo site. This is the demo https://brm.io/matter-js/demo/#slingshot i am referring to. I have also updated the post with the link. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixes:

(1) Change your `world22` element from `canvas` to a `div`, or to any other suitable element. Apparently matter.js will create it's own canvas in the container and thus can't do anything with canvas inside a canvas.

(2) There is a missing `||` in your condition here causing a syntax error, between `rock.position.x > 190 rock.position.y < 430`. Don't know if this became a typo when pasting to SO.

(3) Use the property `element` when specifying the container element when creating the render. Don't use `canvas: canvas`. Use `element: canvas`. Regarding here `Render.create({ ... });`

Here is the modified source. I suppose you can safely ignore how I included the matter.js script. I don't know if the version matters and assume you have the latest.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.14.2/matter.js"></script>
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

 //Fetch our canvas
 var canvas = document.getElementById('world22');

    var Engine = Matter.Engine,
        Render = Matter.Render,
        Runner = Matter.Runner,
        Composites = Matter.Composites,
        Events = Matter.Events,
        Constraint = Matter.Constraint,
        MouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint,
        Mouse = Matter.Mouse,
        World = Matter.World,
        Bodies = Matter.Bodies;

    // create engine
    var engine = Engine.create(),
        world = engine.world;

    // create renderer
    var render = Render.create({
        element: canvas,
        engine: engine,
        options: {
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            showAngleIndicator: true,
        }
    });

    Render.run(render);

    // create runner
    var runner = Runner.create();
    Runner.run(runner, engine);

    // add bodies
    var ground = Bodies.rectangle(395, 600, 815, 50, { isStatic: true }),
        rockOptions = { density: 0.004 },
        rock = Bodies.polygon(170, 450, 8, 20, rockOptions),
        anchor = { x: 170, y: 450 },
        elastic = Constraint.create({ 
            pointA: anchor, 
            bodyB: rock, 
            stiffness: 0.05
        });

    var pyramid = Composites.pyramid(500, 300, 9, 10, 0, 0, function(x, y) {
        return Bodies.rectangle(x, y, 25, 40);
    });

    var ground2 = Bodies.rectangle(610, 250, 200, 20, { isStatic: true });

    var pyramid2 = Composites.pyramid(550, 0, 5, 10, 0, 0, function(x, y) {
        return Bodies.rectangle(x, y, 25, 40);
    });

    World.add(engine.world, [ground, pyramid, ground2, pyramid2, rock, elastic]);

    Events.on(engine, 'afterUpdate', function() {
        if (mouseConstraint.mouse.button === -1 && (rock.position.x > 190 || 
 rock.position.y < 430)) {
            rock = Bodies.polygon(170, 450, 7, 20, rockOptions);
            World.add(engine.world, rock);
            elastic.bodyB = rock;
        }
    });

    // add mouse control
    var mouse = Mouse.create(render.canvas),
        mouseConstraint = MouseConstraint.create(engine, {
            mouse: mouse,
            constraint: {
                stiffness: 0.2,
                render: {
                    visible: false
                }
            }
        });

    World.add(world, mouseConstraint);

    // keep the mouse in sync with rendering
    render.mouse = mouse;

    // fit the render viewport to the scene
    Render.lookAt(render, {
        min: { x: 0, y: 0 },
        max: { x: 800, y: 600 }
    });


});
</script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="world22"></div>
</body>
<html>
```

I based my debugging by referring to a minimal example provided here https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/wiki/Getting-started ....

At first I didn't catch on to the `canvas` problem, but then I used the browser dev tools and inspected the world22 element. *Another* canvas was nested so that's how I knew.

Comment: This works perfectly! I didn't know of the `canvas` issue, thanks for pointing that out! Knowing that also solves another problem of mine now. Appreciate all the help and patience greatly!